# Rating bar stars don't change

Tags: android, android-layout, ratingbar

In my code I want set my custom stars but it didn't work properly

```
 <RatingBar
                android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:numStars="5"
                android:stepSize="1"
                android:rating="1"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/rating_bar_color"/>
```

rating_bar_color.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background" android:drawable="@drawable/starw30" />
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress" android:drawable="@drawable/star" />
</layer-list>
```

I use this code and what I got in result

[image]

Where the lines is coming from. The stars are the same size as default star size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These lines comes because you are trying to wrap the Rating Bar image by using `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`. So, as a solution you have to provide the height of the rating bar to the size of the image.

If the size of the rating bar image is 20, then try adding

`android:layout_height="20dip"`

This will work for you!

Comment: Why is this accepted, or even an answer at all? the topic is "Rating bar stars don't change" and not "How to fix vertical lines".

Answer (score 1):

Just try `android:layout_height="20sp"` or whatever star sizes you are using.

One more thing, you need to define styles for your customized rating bar:

For example: my_ratingbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="foodRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
        <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/rating_bar_color</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">36dip</item> 
        <item name="android:maxHeight">36dip</item>
    </style>
</resources>
<!--Where 36dp is the size of image and include progress drawable here.
```

Apply this style to the RatingBar by using:

```
<RatingBar   
  ...
   style="@style/my_ratingbar" />
```

Comment: are you sure its `android:layout_width` what matters here? AFAIK, its the `android:layout_height` that matters!

Answer (score 0):

This problem was due to the scaling of the images not being correct. The solution to this is to follow the scale ratios Like this..

ldpi  | mdpi  | tvdpi  | hdpi  | xhdpi | xxhdpi | xxxhdpi

0.75  | 1     | 1.33   | 1.5   | 2     | 3      | 4

Answer (score 0):

Those leaking stars happen when the size of the star asset is different from the size of the rating bar AND the star asset doesn't have a transparent space between the star itself and the bottom border.
For some reason android tries to enlarge the image by duplicating the lowest part of the asset so you could add some transparent space at the bottom of your asset as I did in one of my projects.

tl;dr: add some transparent space under the star asset